# How to convert Json to Array In javascript for chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

How to convert Json data to Array. I can't do this
and I have Json data as :

```js
var setdata = [{
   "data": [{
           "month" : "January",
            "name" : "Alex",
             "count" : 10
   }]
 },
  {
   "data": [{
           "month" : "February",
            "name" : "Alex",
             "count" : 20
  },
  { 
   "data": [{
           "month" : "February",
            "name" : "John",
             "count" : 30
  },
  { 
   "data": [{
           "month" : "February",
            "name" : "Mark",
             "count" : 40
  }]
              },
 {
   "data": [{
           "month" : "March",
            "name" : "Alex",
             "count" : 10
  },
  { 
           "month" : "March",
            "name" : "John",
             "count" : 20
  }]
 }
    ]
```

I want to convert to array as :

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March"]

var data =     [10, 0, 0],
               [0, 20, 10],
               [0, 30, 20],
               [0, 40, 0]
```

I want setdata to create stacked chart.js,can you do this for me?  help me please.
thanks.

Comment: Why can't u try object arry ?

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Please check this format. https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/zpzpbf85/. This would be better for iteration and accessing

Comment: ok, I have this format. How to convert to Array. please

Comment: You wanna do it through programmatically or manually?

Comment: I wanna do it by programmatically.

Comment: May i know in which basis the value grouping should happen? Its based on name or month?

Comment: Please find the link https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/zpzpbf85/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var data = [{"month":"January","name":"Alex","count":10},{"month":"February","name":"Alex","count":20},{"month":"February","name":"John","count":30},{"month":"February","name":"Mark","count":40},{"month":"March","name":"Alex","count":10},{"month":"March","name":"John","count":20}];

// TO FIND UNIQUE ARRAY
var months = data.map(function(t){ return t.month});
uniqueMonths = months.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return months.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
console.log('UNIQUE MONTHS:- '+uniqueMonths);

var names = data.map(function(t){ return t.name});
uniqueNames = names.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return names.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
console.log('UNIQUE NAMES:- '+uniqueNames);
var countArr = {};
uniqueNames.forEach(function(d){
 var arr = [];
 uniqueMonths.forEach(function(k){
  arr.push(getValue(d,k));
 });
 countArr[d] = arr;
});
console.log('COUNT ARRAY:- '+JSON.stringify(countArr));

// To get value from the array
function getValue(name, month){
 var value = 0;
 data.forEach(function(d){
  if(d.name == name && d.month == month){
   value = d.count;
  }
 });
 return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but how to remove array from [ [10,20,10],[0,30,20],[0,40,0] ] => [10,20,10],[0,30,20],[0,40,0] becuase I created chart it's don't show chart.

Comment: thanks. it's could stacked bar chart ?, I'm not sure it's correct?

Comment: @jane cant understand the way u wanna represent the data. Multiple array items need object or array wrapper . Otherwise it not